# Making an Async Post request in python

Tags: python-3.x, post, async-await, python-asyncio

Use Case: I have an cherrypy server up and running serving requests. I need to send some tracking info about at which stage are we at. But this tracking info being sent shouldn't be a blocker for my code. I don't want to wait for it to finish execution and continue with my code base. If at any point of time later, it returns a Error, I should be able to log that error.

Current Code using the Synchronous way of calling.

```
self.url = '/'.join([self.api_endpoint, "upload"])
body = json.dumps({"d": data})
headers_params = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
args = None

req = six.moves.urllib.request.Request(self.url, args, headers_params)
req.data = body.encode('utf-8')

try:
     # Open the request
     f = six.moves.urllib.request.urlopen(req)
     # Get the response
     response = f.read()
     # Close the opened request
     f.close()

except Exception as e:
     logger.exception("api exception %s" % e)
     return None

return response
```

How Can I ideally make this as a async post request?

Comment: Cherrypy doesn't support asyncio, so you can't use that kind of async there. Also, your code appears to be written to support Python 2 (it uses `six`). Async/await is unavailable on Python 2.

Comment: You should take a look at libraries like [Celery](https://pypi.org/p/celery) and [RQ](https://pypi.org/p/rq) to run your task in the background.

Comment: i want to do something like.... associate a logger to have the response being logged.... kind of a lamda callback associated with that post request..... and continue my work..... dont want my entire code to be part of that await instruction.

P. S. : the code is now ported to 3.7 python. six was introduced to support back compatibility